# How to access ALL the properties defined in multi capabilities?

Tags: protractor

I am defining my multi capabilities like below:

```
multiCapabilities: [{
      browserName: 'chrome',
      platform: 'macOS 10.14',
      version: 'latest',
      name: 'Chrome tests',
      shardTestFiles: true,
      maxInstances: 1,
      extendedDebugging: true,
}]
```

I am able to access some of the properties by:

```
browser.driver.getCapabilities().then(function(caps){
   console.log(caps);
   console.log(caps.get('browserName'));
});
```

I am not able to find/log the properties like shardTestFiles and maxInstances. How can I access those properties in my tests?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [getProcessedConfig](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.getProcessedConfig).
For example you can firstly `console.log()` entire return object:

```js
    const  = await browser.getProcessedConfig();
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
    console.log(JSON.stringify(config));
```

For getting something specific just get it like in any plain object. For example in my case:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(a.capabilities));
```

I was getting:
`{"browserName":"chrome","shardTestFiles":true,"maxInstances":3,"count":1}`

Hope you got an idea.

Comment: @user12253286 if it post helps you, please, approve it as right answer, thanks.